# UITableviewCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath disable callback when cell has buttons in it

Tags: uitableview

Am not sure if this can be done, but the tableViewCell subclass that I've created has some buttons in it. I need to perform an action based on those button clicks, but no action on didSelectRowAtIndexPath... I have other tableViewCell subclass in the same table for which I do need to perform didSelectRowAtIndexPath.. Is there a way to switch OFF didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the former tableViewCell subclass, but keep it for the later.. instead of ignoring the former in didSelectRowAtIndexPath based on tags or indexPaths?

Answer (score 0):

You can override "setSelected" in your subclass to just ignore the selection. That way, all cells of that particular subclass will ignore selection, but the other UITableViewCells and other subclasses will still work as usual.

e.g.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```